# How to parse entire DOM elements and follow changes in DOM using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a URL which I want to test the changes in it if I browse to this URL several time , meaning:
If this is the first time that a test is running on this url, only save the layout (DOM) of the page.
and I want to be able to produce output which will contain the following:
list of all changes on this url, changes mean - new HTML elements added to the page,
old elements was removed, elements location have changed.

So far what I started to do with selenium is:

```
public String extractingUrlDom(){
        this.driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        this.str = driver.getPageSource().toString();
        return str;
    }
```

My question is how do I track all changes that was done to the DOM after browsing to the same URL (if any changes were done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write the HTML to a text file in a specific location. When a test runs, it would check that location for the expected filename. If it doesn't exist, it's the first time the test was run and it would save the HTML to the file. If a file does exist, you would open the existing file and do a diff of the two HTML strings. You could then write that diff out to a separate file.

There's more logic that you would want to consider but this should be enough to get you started. There are plenty of diffing engines/libraries out there, you should be able to find an existing one and use it.

Comment: OK , Let's say I extracted the file into my local directory and then I extract another HTML string to the same directory and now I am checking file hashing between them in order to see if there are any differences if file hash is different I would perform diff between them.
Another question rises is how to prettify after performing 'driver.getPageSource().toString();'

Comment: You are right.... that is a whole other question. :) Having said that, don't ask it... google it because it's been asked before. If you do some simple googling, you will surely find an HTML prettify library that you can use.

Comment: would it be nicer to parse all DOM and represent it as a tree and then check for changes?

Comment: That would be a question you should ask yourself. I have no idea what the goal or intent of this project is, what you intend to do with the results, etc.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: Nothing I just have to do what I was asking in my question... to check for changes in the DOM.

Comment: A simple diff of the before and after will give you exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: can you suggest of such tool that can make the diff?

Comment: I don't know of one for Java but I'm sure if you googled some, you could find one but this discussion is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.